# Will our biological bodies be changed after we’ve occupied and settled Mars?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, evolution, origins

I had this question in mind for very long time, and I could not find a clear answer on the Internet, so I was hoping that you might know the answer.

If we will bring life to planet Mars and a few years later after it turned into a habitable zone, then we will colonize it according to some rumors. But when we colonized Mars after it is turned into a green world like ours, then would our biological body be changed and new origins will be formed? I mean, it will be changed to the point where we will be able to distinguish who’s Martian and who is from Earth? Or, they would still have Earth as their origin?

Just in curiosity.

Can someone please tell me about this matter? I’m trying to understand how things work in our bodies.

Please correct me if I have chosen wrong tags.

Comment: We welcome new contributors to SE Biology, but we do ask that they take a moment to read about the scope of the site and the sort of questions that are on-topic here. To quote from the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour), this "is a question and answer site for biology researchers, academics, and students" — it is not a discussion site. And from the [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." So, though perhaps interesting to discuss, your question is off-topic here.

Comment: David, the question is not off topic. The question might need to be formed a bit better, however, it is concerning biology, human-biology, and is related to genetics and origins. I think another good tag would be evolution.

Comment: The question is making an assumption, that is is certain that humans could establish a self-perpetuating colony on Mars.  (Rather than just research bases, like the ones in Antarctica.)  It would be better asked with a very large IF.  That said, if such a thing happened, and the two populations were reproductively isolated, of course they would diverge, and eventually - a million years or so - become different species.

Comment: @takintoolong — It's not explained anywhere obvious, but you should use the @ handle when addressing comments to people other than the poster, otherwise they don't get alerted. As for it not being off-topic, I don't think "we will colonize (Mars)… according to some rumours" represents an "actual problem the poster faces". And really it is not anything that biology researchers, academics, and students are likely to concern themselves with on a serious Q&A site, which  is what this purports to be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IF we inhabit Mars, it is very likely that our bodies will change. Separation of species is a very common factor for evolution to occur. It is theorized that our continents used to be attached in some places and when they separated animals on each continent evolved differently. There have been other forms of separation which occurred on Earth such as the formation of glaciers, rivers, and mountain ranges. https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/her/tree-of-life/a/species-speciation

Although physical changes in our appearance are likely, they would also likely take thousands of years to occur. The differences between "Earthlings" and "Martians" would also depend on how much the two planets interact. It would also be possible for our own future "Earthlings" to look much different than we do today.